# CoreData: Ubiquity: Using local storage: 1 never becomes 0

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios7, icloud

I am working on upgrading an App with iOS6's CoreData+iCloud to iOS7. According to the Apple's WWDC video, **"CoreData: Ubiquity: Using local storage: 1"** shall become **"CoreData: Ubiquity: Using local storage: 0"**, when CoreData get ready the iCloud Core Data store.

I have successfully tested this on the simulator. The funny thing is that this never happens to my iPhone 5. I have checked the iCloud Settings in **Setting**, but still have no luck.

Image attached below is the screenshot from xCode's iCloud Debugging panel. Interestingly, there is a baseline.zip file that I could never get it **Current**. This shall be the zombie file from iOS6's iCloud... Is it related?

Any help is appreciated.

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: I have met this problem.Sometimes it switch to "using local storage: 0"

Comment: Are you waiting long enough ?  It can take a while.  Take a look at the link below where I have posted sample code and a video of the app working.  Usually the iPhone 5 takes considerably longer than the simulator or the iPad to pick up and download new files from iCloud. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/

Comment: I have solved the problem by resetting... I guess the iCloud of the App of the Device ran into an uncertain state, and stuck... Suggested solutions: 1) reset by following http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5824. 2) or, simply delete the app and all the data in iCloud from all devices, start over again

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons this could be happening. The simulator may not have iCloud set up properly, but you said that it is, so I will write that one off. Another reason is that you have not enabled iCloud in the Target's Capabilities. Make sure that switch is on. Another cause could be that the simulator does not trigger iCloud sync automatically. Try going to Debug->Trigger iCloud Sync, or press Shft+Cmd+I.

Edit: If you want to use someone else's code (which I have found to be stable), look at this Github project: https://github.com/mluisbrown/iCloudCoreDataStack/blob/master/iCloudCoreDataStack/AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue, when my iPhone is using cellular only. If I enable Wifi, then it works. That is very disappointing!